# Is it possible to start appium server on remote machine (mac)?

Tags: java, testing, mobile, appium

I have a windows machine, where my code repository is and where I start appium server programatically. Now I have a mac, where my iPhone is connected to. I have installed Appium and can connect remotely to the running appium server to execute the testcase from my windows machine. But I need to make sure, that the server is already running on the mac. Is there a way to start the appium server remotely from my windows machine?

Any ideas how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U could install openssh on the Mac and connect to it from your windows machine, then launch appium in a shell from your windows machine.

`brew install openssh`

then from windows

`ssh useronmac@macipaddress`

`appium`